# Installing Older Version of Module in Active Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, activeperl

I am trying to install the Date::Manip Module in Perl. I am running Perl Version 5.14.2 and it does not seem to be installing successfully through the PPM. (PPM throws a 401 Access required error). I am guessing that the error here is that the Version of Perl is outdated for the module in the ppm. Since this is in the server and there are many other scripts running on a day to day basis, I can not upgrade the Perl version. I need to install the previous version of the Date::Manip module but this is not found in the ppm. How do I go about doing this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the 401 error occurs is because you are using ActivePerl 5.14 which is no longer considered as a Community Edition. This means you no longer have access to the PPM server to install modules unless you buy a license from ActiveState.

See here for reference http://community.activestate.com/taxonomy/term/515

You have several options:

- You could buy an ActiveState Business Edition License which will give your access to the PPM repository again.
- If you have MinGW and dmake installed, you can install this module from CPAN instead. Just enter `cpan Date::Manip` in the command-line.
- Upgrade to the latest version of ActivePerl. (But you'll have the same problem again when this version expires.)
- You could install another Perl distribution, like [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: As the OP has said that updating perl itself is not an option, your 2nd & 3rd options are of no value to him.  Though another option is available.  The manager who forbids upgrade of perl engine can spring for an Activestate Business/Enterprise license to allow access to the repository....

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below link and download then install.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip