# ppm gives "401 Authorization Required"

Tags: perl, activeperl

Running AS perl on Win7, on command line:

I type: ppm install Math-Round

I get:

```
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...done
Updating ActiveState Package Repository database...done
Downloading Math-Round-0.06...redirect
Downloading Math-Round-0.06...failed 401 Authorization Required
ppm install failed: 401 Authorization Required
```

Why? And what can I do about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993799/installing-older-version-of-module-in-active-perl

Comment: The short and effective answer is: cpan Math::Round